# Is there a `ufunc` that just forwards the data?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a `ufunc` that just forwards the data?

It's not difficult to achieve the same effect in most cases, but sometimes when explicitly working with ufuncs, it would be convenient to have one that just forwards the data. Mostly for testing/debugging and to have a consistently looking code.

For example, when I have a function that takes an ufunc as an argument:

```
op = some ufunc
x = do_with_op(data0, data1, op)
```

Comment: You could always do something like `np.add(a,0)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It's for sure not difficult to achieve the goal. I edited an use case into the question...

Comment: `lambda x: x` fits

Comment: @ev-br: No, that is WRONG. An ufunc is a bit more than just a function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufunc)

Comment: I know, thank you. Please show a case where this lambda is not enough.

Comment: Are you expecting `x == data0` or `x == data1` here? Your question is not clear

Comment: @ev-br: In any case where the function requires a complete ufunc.

Comment: I think, the question is clear: Is there a ufunc that just forwards the data? Either you know that there's none, then write that. Or you know one, then write that. Or you know a clear reason why there can't be one, then write that. Those low quality hacks proposed really don't help.

Comment: What does "forward" mean for a ufunc that takes two arguments, as in your example? You still haven't answered my question

Comment: This question doesn't make sense if you want a binary `ufunc`.  You can't map 2 to 1 in a pass-through sense.

Comment: Among the binary `ufunc`, `add` will be as simple and fast as any.  It's hard to conceive of a simpler way to combine 2 numbers into 1.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is all real, then [`np.conj(x)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.conj.html#numpy.conj), the complex conjugate, is the identity *unary* ufunc.

---

You can also create your own ufuncs with [`np.frompyfunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html):

```
forward_unary  = np.frompyfunc(lambda x:    x, 1, 1)
forward_first  = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: x, 2, 1)
forward_second = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: y, 2, 1)
```